# React how to handle app versioning and copyright year?

Tags: reactjs, nrwl

I have a react app built with Nrwl that has a footer. In the footer I have the copyright and the version number. What is the best way to dynamically set those?

1. I can get the current year easily. But I am concerned with the device datetime.
2. The version number. Should I set statically or read from JSON file?

How do you tackle this?

Comment: I would suggest https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/ to inject version information into the code at build time

Answer (score 1):

### **Short Answer:**

1. Yes, you can fetch Date from a free API like (http://worldtimeapi.org/) giving a Date object on the time zone or area provided.
2. The version number must be inferred from `package.json` to maintain versioning.

### **Long Answer:**

1. You can hit the below API with the physical location of the business or brand. So you will get the time for the actual location where your business reside.

> `http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Dublin`

This will give a you a response like following, you can easily get year and further in this.

```
{"abbreviation":"GMT","client_ip":"39.42.97.186","datetime":"2021-02-01T11:09:53.942753+00:00","day_of_week":1,"day_of_year":32,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":-3600,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Dublin","unixtime":1612177793,"utc_datetime":"2021-02-01T11:09:53.942753+00:00","utc_offset":"+00:00","week_number":5}
```

2. You can add a global variable in your webpack config as mentioned following, that gives you the package version value in your application.

```
const PACKAGE = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  // Other stuff
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      APP_VERSION: PACKAGE.version 
    });
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wants to contribute to the above answer, the best way to show the app version is to read from the package.json file and you can easily do it by:

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version react-scripts start"
}
```

Then anywhere inside the app you can access the version number using `process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION`

you can read more here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2466#issuecomment-312016096